# How do I save a multiline string to a YAML file?

Tags: yaml, multiline

I have several YAML files that store SQL scripts in them (as multiline strings). I have a Python script that takes all of these scripts and aggregates them into a single table.

Whenever I make an update to a YAML file, it converts the SQL text to a regular string (with `\n`'s to indicate line breaks). Is there a way to preserve the multiline formatting when I make updates to the YAML file?

Comment: What code do you use to create a YAML file now? Please show a [mre].

Answer (score 5):

For multi-line scalars, you can use blocks. The [pipe symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar) character `|` to denote the start of a block.

For example:

```yaml
Data: |
      Some data, here and a special character like ':'
      Another line of data on a separate line
```

Also you can check the [YAML Multiline](https://yaml-multiline.info/)